# ORMLite stacktrace error without further log entries

Tags: android, orm, stack-trace, ormlite

We are getting quite frequently following error, which is only displayed in verbose log level:

```
05-24 13:24:35.627 V/SQLiteCursor: Cursor open object=52072473
    java.lang.Throwable: stacktrace
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:117)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:50)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1285)
        at com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.JellyBeanApiCompatibility.rawQuery(JellyBeanApiCompatibility.java:21)
        at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:193)
        at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:72)
        at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForFirst(StatementExecutor.java:106)
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForFirst(BaseDaoImpl.java:240)
```

Do you have any hints? There are no cursor leaks afaik, so I'm really not sure why I see this message so often. This also happens when I start my app completely clean and don't do much sql writing/reading work...?

This is full exception, there is no more information showing up. The strange thing is also, that this error is only shown in verbose-logging and not showing up in higher log levels..

It looks like it's not related to multiple processes accessing the database - we get the error in our application in single process-mode and also in multi-process-mode (services seperated to multiple processes)..

I'm also not sure if this is hardware-vendor specific, since I don't get these errors in my android studio emulator :(

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I created a ticket: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/issues/142